# How to stop YouTube player from showing related videos?

Tags: youtube, video

How can I stop the YouTube player from showing related video thumbnails and links?
I am in search of YouTube video code that shows only the videos in our YouTube stream, i.e., only the [videos](http://www.youtube.com/user/nividhondemand) we have uploaded.

Answer (score 3):

1. If your URL contains any parameters then add `&rel=0` at the end of it

   i.e., `http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=joYtqNtZe6w&feature=plcp` then add `&rel=0`

   so for example check at last

   http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=joYtdfdsNtZe6w&feature=plcp&rel=0
2. If your URL does not have any parameters then add `?rel=0` at the end of it

   i.e., `http://www.youtube.com/embed/joYtqNtZe6w` then add `?rel=0`

   so

   http://www.youtube.com/embed/joYtqNtZe6w?rel=0

> **Note:** This feature is not available from Sep-2018.

Comment: This feature was removed in September, 2018. https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#rel