# Prevent offering other videos once a YouTube video is over

Tags: youtube, video

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to stop YouTube player from showing related videos?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/17425/how-to-stop-youtube-player-from-showing-related-videos)

I want to have a permanent spot for a specific video I uploaded to YouTube. The problem is that once the video is over, I get auto recommendations for other videos I don't want to recommend.

How can I prevent this?

Answer (score 2):

`rel=0`

on the end of you link in the embed code see examples below:

with suggestions:

```
<iframe width="425" height="349" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/oj9U-Ux6QHY" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

without suggestions:

```
<iframe width="425" height="349" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/oj9U-Ux6QHY?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```